# Select most recent records by DB2 date in form of YYYYMMDD

Tags: sql, db2

I am importing records from a DB2 data source into a MS SQL Server destination.
The records are coming in with the date format of `20150302/YYYYMMDD`, but I only want the last 14 days based on current server date.

Can some advise on how to select based on this date format against `DATEADD(d, - 1, { fn CURDATE() })` please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to do this on the DB2 side, to reduce the number of records brought over.

Additionally, it's better from a performance standpoint to convert the static date into a numeric date and compare to the column in your table.  Rather than convert the numeric date in your table to a actual date type for comparison.

```
where numdate >= int(replace(char(current_date - 14 days,iso),'-',''))
```

Doing it this way will allow you to take advantage of an index over numdate.  In addition, DB2 will only need to perform this conversion once.

Depending on your platform & version, you may have an easier way to convert from a date data type to a numeric date.  But the above works on DB2 for i and should work on most (all?) DB2 versions and platforms.

You may find it worthwhile to create a UDF to do this conversion for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want logic in SQL Server, then you are in luck, because you can just convert the YYYYMMDD format to a date:

```
where cast(datecol as date) >= cast(getdate() - 14 as date)
```

(This assumes no future dates.)

If you want to do this on the DB2 side, you can use `to_date()`:

```
where to_date(datecol, 'YYYYMMDD') >= current date - 14 days
```